# Not enough permissions when editing posts query for author administration panel plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin that is supposed to hook on the posts query and add some parameters to it.

It should work like this:

*Note: We are in the authors admin panel.*

- An author click on "Show me all the posts"
- In the link there are some parameters
- The plugin receive the hook with `add_filter( 'parse_query', 'sgcp_posts_filter' );`
- I edit the query with parameters
- Wordpress show me a list of my filtered posts.

Now, with an **Administrator Role** user it works, but it doesn't with an **Author Role** user .

It sends me back the extremely useful message:

`You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page.`

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'sgcp_posts_filter' );

function sgcp_posts_filter( $query ){

    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }    

    if ( 'nf_sub' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['study_groups']) && $_GET['study_groups'] != '') {
        $params=$_GET['study_groups'];
        $query->set('meta_query' , array(
            array(
                'key'   =>  '_field_44',
                'value' =>  $params
                )
            ));
    }


}
```

**Note**: If I comment the `$query->set...` inside the if statement I don't get the permissions problems anymore.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to the problem.
What I did wrong was to use a dynamic url on a menu link, while using [Admin Menu Editor plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-always-shows-you-dont-have-permissions?replies=3#post-7677256) (very nice plugin).
The plugin indeed use the **url** of the menu element to identify it.

Since it was changing every time with the parameters I had to pass to the query, every time it was using **default permissions** to access that menu element. As you can guess, `author` role was not authorized by default, thus firing the `You don't have enough permissions...` alert.

The **solution** was to move the logic to find the parameters inside the page called by the menu element.